# Trigger svg line animation on screen view and reset it off screen view

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, scrollreveal.js

```
here's a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/20zhrw1o/
```

As the title says, I want to trigger the lines animation on when in screen view and reset it so that if i scroll back to it the animation starts again, I'm not good at js so thanks for any kind help!

also is it possible doing this with scrollreveal plugin?

Comment: Please don't try to subvert the stackoverflow check that you provide actual code in the question when you add a fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS animations are hard to control directly through JavaScript (https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/), so it's better to add and remove CSS classes to start/reset the animation.

```
path {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width:2px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
svg.in-view path {  
    animation: dash 20s linear forwards;
}
```

On every `scroll` event, see if the SVG is on-screen:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    svg.classList.toggle('in-view', isElementInViewport(svg));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/20zhrw1o/1/

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i was looking for, and useful link to use later